# What is the name of this function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$?

Tags: functions, definition

$f(x\in\mathbb{R}) = \frac{1}{1+x^n}$

Comment: Hereafter, the "Guillaume Thomas function".

Comment: @DavidMitra Make it an answer

Comment: Is this a trick question or is the answer really "$f(x)$"?

Comment: [A note about my edit: I didn't improve the formatting; I changed the title. The predictive text on my phone included the formatting bit. Sorry :) ]

Answer (score 8):

This function $f$ can be pronounced phonetically as "One over the sum of one and $x$ to the $n$th power".

Comment: Be careful with the spacing of this. It might be misinterpreted. For example, someone might think it describes $\frac11+x^n$.

Comment: Perhaps "One over the sum of one and ex to the nth power" is better as better as it cant be confused with $\frac{1}{1} + x^n$

Answer (score 2):

In the particular case where $n$ is even, this looks like the pdf of the [Cauchy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), so you might want to say that $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^{2n}}$ is some kind of a generalized Cauchy...

Answer (score 1):

Not every function deserves a name beyond the one it defines for itself by merely describing it (like in Ethan's answer).

EDIT: I would emphasise the spacing to avoid ambiguity:

> One over $\quad$ one plus $\quad x$ to the $n$th power.